# Messed up really hard 777

Tags: permissions

So, I didnt know doing this sudo chmod -R 777 / would completely destroy everything i cant access to ssh neither sftp i dont have any backup there is work of months... btw im using a dedicated of OVH, os ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Is this a remote machine? Or do you have physical access? What kind of "work of months"? Documents? Code? Or system setup/configuration?

Comment: If I understand correctly that your thing runs on OVH's infrastructure and as long as you are after code/documents (oops databases?), you can ask them to make you a copy of your disk, I would imagine... Possibly it's a feature on some admin interface you can access?